# Second Screen With Workers

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flex4

I'm having a little bit of trouble getting up a second window in Flash.

I have already a second screen working, bit it's reaaaaally slow when I use the touch screen to play with the elements on it and I came to the conclusion that is due to the poor use of my computer resources (not more of the 15% of the CPU use, less than s 10% of memory and no GPU use).

Any ideas how to improve this issue?

I thought about the workers, one worker handling the main screen and another worker handling de second, but I can't get the workers and the second screen working properly.

Here comes some of my code:

**--MAIN--**

```
public function activateSecondScreen(evt:Event = null):void{

    if(Worker.current.isPrimordial && firstTime){
        firstTime = false;
        initWorker();
    } 
        //If not the main thread, we're the worker
    else {

        secondaryWindow = new SecondWindow();
    }
}

protected function initWorker():void {
    //Create worker 
    worker = WorkerDomain.current.createWorker(loaderInfo.bytes,true);
    worker.addEventListener(Event.WORKER_STATE,activateSecondScreen);
    //Create message channel TO the worker
    mainToBack = Worker.current.createMessageChannel(worker);

    //Create message channel FROM the worker, add a listener.
    backToMain = worker.createMessageChannel(Worker.current);
    backToMain.addEventListener(Event.CHANNEL_MESSAGE, onBackToMain, false, 0, true);

    //Now that we have our two channels, inject them into the worker as shared properties.
    //This way, the worker can see them on the other side.
    worker.setSharedProperty("backToMain", backToMain);
    worker.setSharedProperty("mainToBack", mainToBack);

    //Lastly, start the worker.
    if (worker.state != WorkerState.RUNNING)
    {
        worker.start();
    }
}

protected function onBackToMain(event:Event):void {
    var msg:String = backToMain.receive();
    if(msg == "SHARPEN_COMPLETE"){
        //Futures Uses
    }
    trace(msg);
}
```

I want my worker to start SecondScreen object.

**--SECONDSCREEN.AS--**
public class SecondWindow extends Sprite
    {

```
    public var secondWindow:NativeWindow;

    public function SecondWindow()
    {
        super();
        initSecondWindow();
    }

    private function initSecondWindow():void{
        var secondWindowinitOptions:NativeWindowInitOptions = new NativeWindowInitOptions();
        secondWindowinitOptions.transparent = true;
        secondWindowinitOptions.systemChrome = NativeWindowSystemChrome.NONE;
        secondWindowinitOptions.type = NativeWindowType.UTILITY;
        secondWindowinitOptions.renderMode = NativeWindowRenderMode.GPU;

        secondWindow = new NativeWindow(secondWindowinitOptions);
        secondWindow.title = "Second Window";
        secondWindow.alwaysInFront = false; //true

        var activar:Boolean = false;
        var screenArray:Array = Screen.screens;
        for(var i:int = 0 ; i< screenArray.length ; i++){
            if(screenArray[i].bounds.x != 0 || screenArray[i].bounds.y != 0){
                secondWindow.bounds = (screenArray[i] as Screen).bounds; //TODO: 
                activar = true;
            }
        }

        secondWindow.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
        secondWindow.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        secondWindow.stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        secondWindow.activate();

    }

}
```

That way I want to open a new window for later pass through some images, videos or whatever.

The line `secondWindow.activate();` is not working properly, the same code without workers , gets the window up. 
I would appreciate any ideas.

Thank you.

Comment: Although it is not stated explicitly, the idea behind (secondary) workers is to process large amounts of data in the background to avoid a risk of blocking the main application (thus to worsen the user experience) thread. It is not impossible (you need to debug and diagnose it to be sure) that secondary workers have no access to windows, cameras, mouse, keyboard, and any other possible human-related interface.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I never imagined that workers had so many restrictions. Have you any ideas how to ease the burden on the main application? Because it realy slows down and it only use one of the eight cores of the CPU. Thanks again.

Comment: Figure, why it is "lagging". Could be something really simple, like low FPS value for the secondary window stage.

Comment: Did you try to use Adobe Scout for profiling? If not it's definitely worth checking.

Comment: @Organis, I don't think is low FPS on the second window because both windows get the 'lag' (thats why I thought about theading).

Comment: @3vilguy never used that before, I'll check it out thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind the render mode for the second window is set to use the gpu so you might not see that much usage on another core. I would go by what Organis said though. Workers are best used for background tasks. If your window is running slow use Adobe Scout to see how you can improve your functions.